# How to add a pdfview in flutter for web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

i want  to view a webpage in flutter app . The web page contains pdf file and WebView package
shows a blank screen . Any ways to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

A better approach in my opinion would be using a package like [this](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer) to render the pdf. So instead of using a WebView to render the pdf, download it locally and use the package.

Comment: This also shows a blank page . Actually the site doesnot only render a pdf. canyou please look for https://www.digicoachme.com/sales-policy/ . That package shows a blank screen

Comment: Hey, try opening that webpage in incognito mode. It turns out that you need to accept cookies before you're able to view the actual site.
[This](https://s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/digicoachme.com/uploads/CGV.pdf) is the actual URL of the pdf file

Comment: How can i accept that Programmatically?

Comment: I'm not sure that is an easy way to do that. I think you should download the pdf file and have it stored locally in your app. Then use any of the pdf viewer packages to display it. (Or use the URL I've shown in my previous reply)